# jQuery how to get paragraph's width in px?

Tags: jquery, width, pnotify

I have the following;

```
<div class="pin">
<p class="pin-text hidden">text</p>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
form.on('mouseover', '.pin', function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    if($('#' + id).children('p.pin-text').length) {
        pin_text_width = ($('#' + id).children('p.pin-text').parent().width()).toString() + 'px';
        pin_text = $('#' + id).children('p.pin-text').text();
    }
});
```

I need to find the paragraph's text width in order to size a PNotify tooltip with variable width:

```
tooltip = new PNotify({
    text: pin_text,
    width: pin_text_width,
    ....
```

How can I calculate the text (words) width?

Comment: Firstly your `.pin` elements have no `id`. Secondly you can just do `$(this)` to get the element instead of getting the `id` and concatenating it to a selector

Comment: ok, but that doesn't solve the width problem

Comment: That's why it's a comment. There's not really enough context about your tootlip library, and how exactly it combines with the calculated widths of the `p` element - especially if there are multiple `p` elements. Are you defining multiple tooltips, or one single instance? A working example would help a lot

Comment: A working example is a thousand lines long. I display pins with appended text dynamically (from a DB). If I do alert($(this).children('p.pin-text').parent().html()) - it shows up the whole <p> html. But alert($(this).children('p.pin-text').parent().width())  returns a zero width.

Comment: I've realized that's not what I need, I'm trying to get the parent's width, while I need to get a width of the text itself to make that paragraph of that width. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [jQuery width](http://api.jquery.com/width/). Example:

```
var foo = $(".hidden").width();
alert(foo);
```

Comment: That works on its own but it doesn't work on PNotify. I guess it may be something to do with its wrapper elements.

Comment: You can inspect it with firebug/chrome dev tools and see the width reported there.